# Post reviews, what to do when options don't fit circumstance

Tags: discussion

I'm beginning to do some post reviewing in my spare time and have run into quite a few circumstances where I just hit the Skip button because I'm not sure that my options fit the circumstances.

[Sweet Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/does-sweet-coffee-exist/3700#3700)

This is a good example of what I am talking about.  We have options to basically approve, delete or skip this post.  I was hoping I might get some advice on how other reviewers handle this type of question.  Should we be very critical of the posts to maintain high quality, or be lenient and let a post like the answer above slide and maybe throw a comment in to the poster to try and get some improvement in answer quality?  The user is brand new, and has posted what essentially comes down to an advertisement, but in such a way that it actually kind of sort of answers the question (in a terrible way).

On the one hand we want to maintain content integrity, but on the other hand, we don't want to be so brutal in our reviewing that it turns users away from the site.  I would like to determine what the current consensus is on reviewing practices, or at least throw some ideas around to figure out how strict I should be when performing reviews.

Comment: I can’t comment, because I am not sure which answer you are referring to. It seems the link is to the question, not an answer?